# Select Parent li as active when child li is active using php multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, menu, parent-child, parent

I do not want to turn to jQuery for this solution. I just want to select the parent `$key` of the active `$value` in the php array so that when the sub menu tab is active, the parent tab is active too.

Example: In the array below, the `Engineer` key has an array within it to specify the sub pages that drop down beneath that tab in the menu. When one of these sub pages is selected, how can I make the parent tab active by climbing the array to get the `$key` of the `$value` that is selected?

I'm using url parameters and not directories. The only directory being used is `/jobs/` and the url parameters are `?position=`.

A full url will look like:

```
http://computerhelpwanted.com/jobs/?position=Software+Engineer
```

So I have already figured out how to set sub menu tabs active, now I just need to set top level tabs active when its sub menu tab is active.

I'll be adding another condition to this statement in the example code below.

```
    if (strpos($position,$filename) !== false) {
        $attr_current = ' class="current"';
    } else {
        $attr_current = '';
    }
```

It only works partially the way it is with the `if (strpos($position,$filename) !== false)` condition, however this won't always be true. Sometimes `$position` will not be in `$filename` and in this case I need an alternative solution. Preferably by just including a condition that says `(when $value is selected, also select the parent $key)`

**Array:**

```
    // Menu Items
    $li_1 = 'Engineer';

    $pages = array(
        // Engineer
        $li_1 => array(
            'pageTitle' => $li_1,
            'subpages' => array(
                'Software '.$li_1 => 'Software',
                'Embedded Software '.$li_1 => 'Embedded Software',
                'Computer '.$li_1 => 'Computer',
                'Systems-'.$li_1 => 'Systems',
                'Graphics '.$li_1 => 'Graphics',
                'Research Development '.$li_1 => 'R&amp;D',
                'Network '.$li_1 => 'Network',
                'Network Security '.$li_1 => 'Network Security',
                'Technical Support '.$li_1 => 'Technical Support',
            )
        ),
    );
```

**Dynamic menu list:**

```
    <? foreach ($pages as $filename => $value) {

    if (is_array ($value)) {
        $href = '#menu';
        $pageTitle = $value ['pageTitle'];
    } else {
        $href = $dir_structure.$filename;
        $pageTitle = $value;
    }

    if (strpos($position,$filename) !== false || $value == $currentPage) {
        $attr_current = ' class="current"';
    } else {
        $attr_current = '';
    }

    echo '
        <li'.$attr_current.'><a href="'.$href.'">'.$pageTitle.'</a>';

    if (is_array ($value)) {
    echo '
            <ul class="subMenu">';
    foreach ($value ['subpages'] as $subfilename => $subpageTitle) {

    if ($subfilename == $position) {
      $attr_current = ' class="current"';
    } else {
      $attr_current = '';
    }
    echo '
                <li'.$attr_current.'><a href="'.$dir_structure.'jobs/?position='.urlencode($subfilename).'">'.$subpageTitle.'</a></li>';
    } // foreach subpages

    echo '
            </ul>';

    } // is_array

    echo '
        </li>';

    } // foreach pages
```

Comment: Sounds like you're determining which option is selected at the time you're outputting it. Problem is when you want to select parents as well, they've already been processed. You should loop through your results and assign the "selected" value to each element that needs it where necessary, this way you can go one level up when you need to to select the parent as well. Then loop again to output it.

Comment: can you give me an example code?